# Get world region name from a country name in R

Tags: r, region, country

In my data I have one column with country names. I want to make a new variable that lists which region each country is in based on an excel sheet I have where I have labelled each country by region.

I don't want to use the package countrycode because it doesn't have specific enough regions (i.e. it labels the Netherlands as Europe, and not Northern Europe). Is there a way to get R to inspect a cell and match the contents of that cell to another dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Import your spreadsheet into R.  (Use RExcel, or export as CSV and import that using base functions.)  Suppose your spreadsheet has two columns, named `Country` and `Region`, something like this:

```
regions <- data.frame(Country = c("Greece", "Netherlands"), 
                      Region = c("Southern Europe", "Northern Europe"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
regions
#>       Country          Region
#> 1      Greece Southern Europe
#> 2 Netherlands Northern Europe
```

Now create a named vector from the dataframe:

```
named <- regions$Region
names(named) <- regions$Country
named
#>            Greece       Netherlands 
#> "Southern Europe" "Northern Europe"
```

Now you can index the named vector to convert country names to regions in any other vector.

```
other <- c("Netherlands", "Greece", "Greece")
named[other]
#>       Netherlands            Greece            Greece 
#> "Northern Europe" "Southern Europe" "Southern Europe"
```

If you have any missing countries (or variant spellings), you'll get `NA` for the region, e.g.

```
other2 <- c("Greece", "France")
named[other2]
#>            Greece              <NA> 
#> "Southern Europe"                NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rnaturalearth` library has country shapefiles with region and subregion.

```
library(rnaturalearth)

world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")

world$region
world$subregion
```